# Lazarus: Widgets window do not show anymore

Tags: pascal, lazarus

When using LCL in a Lazarus application, you're supposed to have a window with all the widgets you use appear in the IDE. For some strange reason, I don't have this Windows anymore on one of my projects and looked through Lazarus menus to find it without any success.

Comment: I've never noticed this, but if it happened to only one of your projects, try to compare common parts of the `YourProject.lpi` file with the one from another project where the tool window is visible. It's the file where the session configuration is stored, so I would try to compare the *common* sections of those files.

Comment: Following your advice, I compared two projects (one where the tool window is visible and one where it doesn't show up) and I can't find any difference related to this in the .lpi :/

Isn't there an option in lazarus to force open this tool window ?

Comment: One idea, try to check the size and position of the window. Go through the `Environment / Options...` and in the `IDE Options` window go to `Environment / Window` tree item. There you can setup the size and position of all tool windows, and I hope you might be able to find and modify it there.

Comment: D'oh, you meant the form; I was thinking about some tool window :-) So to form/code toggle in Lazarus you can also use the `F12` key shortcut. Anyway, it's nice, that you've shared the solution, but could you post it as the answer and [`accept it`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541) by your own (I'll vote for it) ? It's for better overview for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: Yay, sorry If my question wasn't clear enough :) ! I didn't know this window was just called "form" as the Form it previews.

I posted my answer, thank you TLama for everything !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be easier than I thought: Clicking on the `Toggle between Unit and Form` button in the upper left (next to the save button) or on the keyboard shortcut `F12` when on the Unit containing your form brings up the forms window.